# how to remove right margin from cardview in gridLayoutManager of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using recyclerView with gridLayoutManager as its layout manager to display the cardViews but I don't know why it has these right margins although I haven't given any margins neither in recyclerView nor in the cardView

[image]

recyclerView code

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayoutTop"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />
```

cardView code

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com   
/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardView1"
android:layout_width="@dimen/_146sdp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/_175sdp"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:strokeColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
app:strokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp">
```

GridLayoutManager

```
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: You're hardcoding the size of the cardview's width, and height. The GridLayout is positioning views in a grid, but no indication was given on where to do it. So it's just left aligned, but since the card's size is harcdoded, any space left is well... left unused.

Answer (score 0):

You set dimen size for the width of `CardView` and items get the size and the left space looks a margin.
you should set width of cell to `match_parent` and `recyclerview` handle the size of width to half of phone width.

Answer (score 0):

when creating that item's layout **width isn't match_parent** because before I had this problem and to fix it follow me:)

well, first to show you the problem without solving the problem then step by step to solving the problem

I created the layout's XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedCorner" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_pictures"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceHeadline5"
            android:textColor="?colorOnSurface"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="cats are beautiful" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="18sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:drawablePadding="4dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceSubtitle1"
            tools:text="dog dog" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

well, as you see, the layout parent's width isn't set as match_parent

and now with the usage ItemDecorator, items design will do

```
 binding.rvGetBreeds.addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        override fun getItemOffsets(
            outRect: Rect,
            view: View,
            parent: RecyclerView,
            state: RecyclerView.State
        ) {
            val leftMargin = 10f
            val rightMargin = 16f
            val topMargin = 10f
            val bottomMargin = 2f
            if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) % 2 == 0) {
                outRect.set(
                    valueConvertToDP(leftMargin).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(topMargin).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(rightMargin / 2).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(bottomMargin).toInt()
                )
            } else {
                outRect.set(
                    valueConvertToDP(rightMargin / 2).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(topMargin).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(leftMargin).toInt(),
                    valueConvertToDP(bottomMargin).toInt()
                )
            }
        }
    })
```

and then result in this is the picture which isn't proportional at all

[image]

now going to adapter's recyclerView and edit view's the width

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeAdapterViewHolder {
    val view =
        ItemRecyclerHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    val layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 230f, parent.resources.displayMetrics
        ).toInt()
    )
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 0
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 0
    layoutParams.topMargin = 0
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0
    view.root.layoutParams = layoutParams
    return HomeAdapterViewHolder(view)
}
```

and finally, this is what we want

[image]

I hope this helps you